# Is there a way on getting Scanner input without having to create an instance of the class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream

Let's say I have this code:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
char x = 'h', aux;
System.out.println("Insert a single letter");
aux=scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (x==aux)System.out.println("match");
```

Is there a way to avoid

```
Scanner scannerobject = new Scanner();
```

and get the work done with a function tool like C's scanf() or fget()?
I was just confused about this!

Comment: This is a "guess what the Java developers were thinking" or "let's discuss what they were thinking" type question, and as such risks being closed as it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: You dont need a scanner class to get std in. `System.in` will do the trick, just like scanf. Scanner exists because it wraps up lots of things you might like to do with std in input.

Comment: well, I thought these people actually keep track of what they do... I don't think is off-topic, I may have explained myself wrong @HovercraftFullOfEels.

Comment: Think about how much less useful static methods for Scanner would be if you had one Scanner for keyboard input and another Scanner for reading form a file.

Comment: Static method implementations are not trivially replaceable with polymorphism; need `scanf` to also perform something else? Too freaking bad.

Comment: Why is people so fast in giving a bad mark? I'm just trying to understand how does this work...

Comment: @PabloGomez Can you really give an answer to an arbitrary question about why you did something 20 years ago?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, bhspencer, user2864740 ... I edited the question to make clear what im trying to ask... Is it still off-topic? would you guys take the bad marks away? is my third question ever in this site so i'm learning how to ask...

Comment: Despite everybody saying there was no answer for my former question, here you are http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/294987/193442

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a Scanner to get input in Java. Scanner is just a high level class for parsing input while reading it. You can read from the static InputSteam `System.in`. Your probably want to wrap it in to with a BufferedReader though since you likely want to deal with Strings more than byte arrays.

e.g.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Scanner object to get input from console or from files to my knowledge but maybe more sources. If your method / class was doing both one after another repeatedly it would be useful to have separate objects to do so. Otherwise all of the configuration would have to be done each time you wanted to get input;